# Multi universal communication

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, universe

With the laws of physics we know today an infinite  multi-universe system is in theory perfectly possible and plausible .

By multi universes I don't intend multiply different copies of our reality or mirrored versions of our universe but completely different, separate universes. each one defined by its own space, energy, matter and possibly even laws of physics

Those universe have nothing to do with each other due to the primary fact that they are  separated, they just happen to coexist.

Given they exist and given we have enough knowledge and  intelligence to develop the  technology needed. Is it possible to cross into another universe or communicate by sending any kind of input to any other universe and see the reaction?

Or is it by definition impossible due to those universes being naturally separated, therefore everything happening in another universe will forever remain there without chance for us to even know?

Comment: [In "Fringe" they used "quantum entangled" typewriters.](http://fringe.wikia.com/wiki/IBM_Selectric_251_typewriter)

Comment: Hi Defiler Isren, and welcome to Worldbuilding. Unfortunately, I find your question to be contradictory. First, mathematical models are just that, *models*, not reality. (We can and do strive to *describe* reality using mathematical models, but those models aren't *actually* reality.) Second, you really don't say anything about how the multiverse in your world works. Third, if we have "all the technology needed" then almost by definition it is "possible" to do something without invoking magic.

Comment: There might be a good question lurking in here, but I don't think this is it. I encourage you to [edit] your question to include more details on how the proposed mechanisms work in your world; then, we *might* be able to come up with answers about how to communicate across such boundaries that don't stress the limits of known physics by *too much*.

Comment: Edited in hope  my question now makes more sense to the eyes of others.

Comment: @InstantMuffin so *not* an example of "science-based".

Answer (score 1):

Questions like this push linguistic limits.  Accordingly, I think there are a few answers I might give.

- It is impossible, by the known laws of physics, to interact with the other universe.  That's why they're called different universes.
- The known laws of physics can change, because we're always learning new things about physics.  There is nothing which prevents us from discovering a new model which permits communication to that which was previously considered to be a "different universe."  This is not saying that we change the laws of physics, merely that we discover some facet where our knowledge of those laws had always been lacking.
- The definition of "universe" could change.  It may be that we *define* the universe to be that which we can [eventually] interact with, and thus the mere act of discovering a way to interact with other universes instantly redefines them such that they are now part of our universe.  It's all semantics at that point.

There are plenty of examples of us having to redefine our world due to new discoveries.  After all, atoms were supposed to be indivisible, until someone figured out how to divide them.  Microscopic scale physics was supposed to be deterministic, until we found things that weren't well modeled that way... now we have quantum physics to describe them.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not as you described it. If the universes are totally different (different laws, particles etc) we will not be able to interact or communicate with them.

1.) Because the universes are separated we cannot make any observations, measurements or predictions.

2.) Even if we could make measurements or observations it wouldn't help much. Because in the other universes are other laws in force than in ours, devices build in one universe will not work in the others. Even our "normal" measuring instruments would properly be useless and unable to detect anything in the other universes.